# Javascript XMLHttpRequest onreadystatechanged not firing?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have an html file and a `.txt` file in the same directory hosted on a webserver.  The html file contains the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

window.onload = function() {
    receiveMessage();
}

function receiveMessage() {

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "message.txt", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechanged = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }       
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Since the text file message.txt contains "hello world", a javascript alert box containing that message should pop up when the response is received, but it's not.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

reorder the request and change function **onreadystatechanged** to **onreadystatechange**:

```
function receiveMessage() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","message.txt",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

put the open and send calls after the onready statechanged event like in http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
   function loadXMLDoc()
   {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
     xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{// code for IE6, IE5
     xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
      document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","demo_get.asp",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h2>AJAX</h2>
  <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Request data</button>
  <div id="myDiv"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I tested in both Chrome and Firefox and it isn't showing the alert box with xmlhttp.responseText.

I had actually tried setting onreadystatechanged event handler before calling xmlhttp.open even before you posted your response and it hadn't worked for me...

Synchronous requests seem to be working, but obviously I need to get Async ones to work also.

Comment: I see you updated your answer, I'll test it out and let you know if that solves it.

Comment: It works for me.  I marked it as the answer.  What was the problem with my original code?  I realize it didn't have the IE 5 and 6 support, but wasn't testing with those browsers.  Was it because I was calling receiveMessage in window.onload's event handler?

Comment: The order doesn't matter. The receiveMessage function will finish running before any events will be handled.

Answer (score -1):

The property you are looking for is `onreadystatechange` not `onreadystatechanged`. There is no `d` on the end.

Comment: @GaneshKamath — Are you commenting on my answer to ask why people were downvoting your answer? I'd speculate that it is because, before you copied my answer into it, it was completely wrong and the code only worked because you rewrote it (or rather, copy/pasted it from another site) without noticing what the significant difference was.

Comment: I have deleted it now

Comment: Thanks guys...neither my console in Firefox or Chrome alerted me to the fact that onreadystatechanged wasn't even an event of XMLHttpRequest objects because of the d at the end...need to work on my attention to detail I suppose, frustrates me sometimes.